# Swift 5 - JSONEncoder with nested JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone

I'm trying to encode a `[[String : String]]` into JSON nested objects with `JSONEncoder()`.

Example of Swift output:

```
[["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"], ["firstName": "Tim", "lastName": "Cook"]]
```

Intended output of JSON after being encoded:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  },

  {
    "firstName": "Tim",
    "lastName": "Cook"
  }
]
```

How would I go about looping through this array of dictionaries and then encoding it with `JSONEncoder().encode()`? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONEncoder gives you `Data` by default. To get it back into `String` form, you can use this:

```
let input = [["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"], ["firstName": "Tim", "lastName": "Cook"]]

do {
    let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(input)
    print(String(decoding: json, as: UTF8.self))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Which yields:

> [{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Tim","lastName":"Cook"}]

Answer (score 1):

Using `Codable` to encode/decode JSON data. Firstly, convert JSON into an object like this, it will make it easier if you update with more fields:

```swift
struct Person: Codable {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}
```

Assume that you have a `Person` array

```swift
var persons = [Person]()
persons.append(.init(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"))
persons.append(.init(firstName: "Tim", lastName: "Cook"))

//PRINT OUT
let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(persons)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
```

And this is the output:

> "[{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Tim","lastName":"Cook"}]"